# Replacing cedar shake siding and adding insulation

Tags: walls, insulation, exterior, sheathing, radiant-barrier

I have old cedar shake siding on a portion of my home, built in the 1950s, and am planning to replace it with a cement siding. Underneath the cedar are nailers, then the open cavity of the wall. In many places there is no insulation, and I plan to add continuous sheathing. I am located in North Texas, with moderate humidity and long hot summers

Can I add fiberglass batt from the outside of the wall?

When I add sheathing, would radiant barrier sheathing be beneficial? With metal on the outside or inside? It would not have the air gap normally required, so housewrap might be a better idea?

Comment: Usually work from the outside to inside when building a house(insulation wise), but not a problem to work backwards.  Will want vapour barrier on the inside wall first, then insulation, sheathing, siding.  Insulation does not like water, so timing on placing insulation and covering(protecting from rain/snow/watering lawn) is important.

Comment: You'd want to tell us about your climate. The location of the vapor barrier can depend on whether you primarily heat or cool. Also, _shingles_, not shakes.